# How to access external db file in Xcode

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am having a .sqlite  file which already generated from some other application. Now I want to include that .sqlite file into Xcode and want to use that data for my(another) IOS Application. In android We can do that specifying the db file path. How can I achieve that in IOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS you can't use other apps data. Actually your app run in a snadbox and you can't access anything outside that sandbox.

Comment: @Bharath welcome to SO.. when you think an answer is correct you should accept it by press the check mark. If you think an answer is helpful to you should upvote it by pressing the up arrow.